# Passing dynamic name from one jsp to another

Tags: java, jsp

I wanted to know, how I could pass a dynamic value from one JSP to another.

For example, I want to know what I need to call to pass the value of name parameter to JSP2, when I clicked on the link in JSP1. I have tried following, but it's not working.

in JPS1:

```
<a href="JPS2.jsp" name="<%= packets.getString("BatchNo")%>">
```

in JPS2:

```
<% String UN = request.getParameter("name");%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the value of `packets.getString("BatchNo")` from `first.jsp` to `second.jsp`, you can do that as below.

**first.jsp :**

```
<a href="jsp2.jsp?name=<%=packets.getString("BatchNo")%>">LINK</a>
```

**second.jsp :**

```
<% String un = request.getParameter("name");%>
```

Comment: Thanks works great. didn't know that the href could take in args and set values in them. learn something new all the time.